# Navigation button over hidden html5 video on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, video

I have a slider with a video in each slide and arrows on the side (outer) of the active slide.
The videos are HTML5.

The problem is that I can't click on the arrow on iPhone although they are outside of the active area.

Also note that the active area has overflow hidden style.

image that explain it better:
[image]